# Print row number in a table

Tags: jquery

Am trying to print < tr > row number in a table of 20 rows.

I'm not so well-versed in jQuery syntax, but this is basically what I need

```
var rowIndex = 1;
// for each row increase rowIndex + 1
$('.tablerow').html(rowIndex)
```

Much thnx for any help you can throw my way.

Comment: Is `.tablerow` each `tr` or is it the first `td` in each `tr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop over the rows. If `.tablerow` is a class on the tr-element, you could loop over each row like this:

```
$('.tablerow').each(function (i) {
   $("td:first", this).html(i);
});
```

The example will add the index to the first td-element on each row.

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLVwJ/)

If you don't want to add the index to the first td-element, your can use the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to select any td you want by specifying its index within the tr-element (zero-based).

```
$('.tablerow').each(function (i) {
   $("td", this).eq(2).html(i);
});
```

Above example will write the index to the third td-element on each row.

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLVwJ/1/)

**Start at one:**

To start at 1 instead of 0, all you have to do is to add one to the index when printing it

```
$('.tablerow').each(function (i) {
   $("td:first", this).html(i + 1);
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLVwJ/3/)

Comment: Thanks tons @christofer-eliasson! Works like a charm. How do I start counting from 1 (rather than 0)?

Comment: Beautiful! @christofer-eliasson!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` to run a custom function on each item in a collection.  You don't show us your exact HTML so we don't know exactly which item `.tablerow` is. Here are two options depending upon what `.tablerow` is:

Assuming `.tablerow` is your `tr`:

```
$(".tablerow td:first").each(function(index) {
    $(this).html(index);
});
```

If `.tablerow` is already the first `td` in each row, then it can just be this:

```
$(".tablerow").each(function(index) {
    $(this).html(index);
});
```